# if a^x + b^y = c^z, 1/x + 1/y + 1/z < 1, how do we call this numbers?

Tags: terminology

I have equation
$a^x + b^y = c^z, 1/x + 1/y + 1/z < 1$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, $z$ are positive integers.

Are there any special name for solutions of this equation?

Comment: https://www.ams.org/notices/199711/beal.pdf

Comment: Yes, it's what I wanted. Thank you!